# Access Denied when calling the CreateInvalidation operation on AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am attempting to create a command that will invalidate CloudFront distribution when pushing out new code. This is an attempt to fix the issue that new HTML pushed out doesn't take up to 24 hours to appear on my web app. The idea comes from this [AWS CLI COMMAND REFERENCE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html)

Here is the command:

aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXXXXXXXXXXXXX --invalidation-batch file://invbatch.json

Here is the response I get when I run the command:

A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:user/cats-kittens-beanstalk-user is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateInvalidation

Any idea why this might be? I know AWS throws this access denied even though the user is authorized to run commands in some instances - see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/673467/access-denied-copying-files-using-s3-cli).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using AWS credentials that don't have permission to invalidate your CloudFront distribution. You should go into the AWS IAM console and look at that user you are using, "cats-kittens-beanstalk-user"??, and add the appropriate permissions to that user.

Alternately, create a new user in IAM that has the appropriate permissions.

> I know AWS throws this access denied even though the user is
>   authorized to run commands in some instances

In the example you link, it appeared to S3 that they were trying to perform an operation on an S3 bucket that they didn't own, or one that didn't exist, so I think the permission error was perfectly appropriate in that instance.

If you are completely sure that your user has the appropriate permissions, then perhaps your distribution-id or something in your .json file is incorrect, causing CloudFront to think you are trying to edit a distribution that you don't own, or one that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you - this is correct. After my permissions were changed, the command worked.